# systemd doesn't read environment variables required for script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, shell, systemd

I want to use `borg` backup and `systemd` timers to do my backups. I am using the script from borg backup website very slightly adjusted. You can see the original [HERE](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#automating-backups) and my script below:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Setting this, so the repo does not need to be given on the commandline:
export BORG_REPO=callmebob@mydomain.com:/path/to/repo

# See the section "Passphrase notes" for more infos.
export BORG_PASSPHRASE=SecretPassphrase

# some helpers and error handling:
info() { printf "\n%s %s\n\n" "$( date )" "$*" >&2; }
trap 'echo $( date ) Backup interrupted >&2; exit 2' INT TERM

info "Starting backup"

# Backup the most important directories into an archive named after
# the machine this script is currently running on:

borg create                            \
    --remote-path=/usr/local/bin/borg  \
    --verbose                          \
    --filter AME                       \
    --list                             \
    --stats                            \
    --show-rc                          \
    --compression lz4                  \
    --exclude-caches                   \
                                       \
    ::'{hostname}-{now}'               \
    ~/.ssh                             \
    ~/db/dump_*                        \

backup_exit=$?

info "Pruning repository"

# Use the `prune` subcommand to maintain 7 daily, 4 weekly and 6 monthly
# archives of THIS machine. The '{hostname}-' prefix is very important to
# limit prune's operation to this machine's archives and not apply to
# other machines' archives also:

borg prune                             \
    --remote-path=/usr/local/bin/borg  \
    --list                             \
    --prefix '{hostname}-'             \
    --show-rc                          \
    --keep-daily    7                  \
    --keep-weekly   4                  \
    --keep-monthly  6                  \

prune_exit=$?

# use highest exit code as global exit code
global_exit=$(( backup_exit > prune_exit ? backup_exit : prune_exit ))

if [ ${global_exit} -eq 0 ]; then
    info "Backup and Prune finished successfully"
elif [ ${global_exit} -eq 1 ]; then
    info "Backup and/or Prune finished with warnings"
else
    info "Backup and/or Prune finished with errors"
fi

exit ${global_exit}
```

ATM I am just trying to set up a service, no timer.

I created `n.service` (working name) in `/etc/systemd/system`, content below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example Service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=callmebob
Group=callmebob
Environment="BORG_REPO=callmebob@mydomain.com:/path/to/repo"
Environment="BORG_PASSPHRASE=SecretPassphrase"
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/callmebob/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targetshell
```

Now from console:

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start n
sudo systemctl status n
```

Service seems to be running OK, but it can never read the environment variables:

```bsh
May 18 05:45:31 mydomain systemd[1]: Started Example Service.
May 18 05:45:31 mydomain sh[213874]: Wed 18 May 05:45:31 UTC 2022 Starting backup
May 18 05:45:38 mydomain sh[213903]: passphrase supplied in BORG_PASSPHRASE, by BORG_PASSCOMMAND or via BORG_PASSPHRASE_FD is incorrect.
May 18 05:45:38 mydomain sh[213903]: terminating with error status, rc 2
```

I tried with `EnvironmentFile`, where I put key/value pairs, no quotes etc, but also didn't work. Using `PassEnvironment` also did nothing. I tried different service types as well, no luck.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you remove the `export BORG_...` lines in the script? If not, the values set there would be used, overriding the ones set by systemd.

Comment: @muru Yes, I commented them out. They were anyway copy/paste. Also if I understand correctly, ENV variables from script would not be read by systemd, because it uses some basic set of variables, no ? This is why we put them in the systemd service in the first place. Correct me if I am wrong :)